# Cmake (< 3.6) compiler flags in custom command

Tags: c++, cmake

Suppose I have a set of compiler flags  and I have two targets

```CMake
set(COMPILE_FLAGS "-a -b -c")

add_executable(exe main.cpp)
set_target_properties(exe PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS ${COMPILE_FLAGS})
add_custom_target(target1 DEPENDS exe)

add_custom_target(target2 DEPENDS exe2)
separate_arguments(COMPILE_FLAGS)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${DEVICE_OBJ_FILE} 
                    COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} ${COMPILE_FLAGS} ${OTHER_FLAGS} main.cpp -o exe2
                    DEPENDS source.cpp)
```

is there anyway to avoid having to call "separate_arguments"

I would rather set FLAGS as semicolon seperated list and COMPILE_OPTIONS instead of COMPILE_FLAGS, but the latest cmake we have access to is 3.6

Comment: "I would rather set FLAGS as semicolon seperated list" - Yes, this is a proper way. And instead of `set_target_properties`, which works only with single-value properties, use [set_property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/set_property.html) command.

Comment: Why do you execute compiler manually? If you want to execute just the compiler, then why use cmake, it will just go in the way? But why not use cmake instead, and do `add_executable(target2 source.cpp)`, what is the point of manually compilng?

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm using a non-standard compiler (DPCPP+) and for target2 I'm actually generating a report. If I use add_executable cmake seems to do its compile and link steps, not exactly what I want.

Comment: Then I suggest to rather write compiler specific configuration files, rather then writing `add_custom_command` all the time. Something [like this](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/Compiler/GNU.cmake). It doesn't actually take that long. But TBH the official readme on DPCPP seems to suggest to just use clang syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[target_compile_options()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/target_compile_options.html?highlight=target_compile_options) goes back to at least CMake 3.0 and should probably be the preferred way to set these kind of flags.  It takes a list.

`CMakeLists.txt` (Note: I used `-D???` as the flags. Normally one should use [target_compile_definitions()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/target_compile_definitions.html#command:target_compile_definitions) for defines.)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

project ("example" CXX)

set(COMPILE_FLAGS -DAYE -DBEE -DSEE)
set(OTHER_FLAGS -DDEE -DEEE)

add_executable(exe main.cpp)
target_compile_options(exe PRIVATE ${COMPILE_FLAGS})
add_custom_command(OUTPUT exe2
                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} ${COMPILE_FLAGS} ${OTHER_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/main.cpp -o exe2
                   DEPENDS main.cpp)
add_custom_target(target2 DEPENDS exe2)
```

`main.cpp` (exe outputs `The sum is 3` while exe2 outputs `The sum is 5`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sum = 0;
#ifdef AYE 
    sum++;
#endif
#ifdef BEE 
    sum++;
#endif
#ifdef SEE 
    sum++;
#endif
#ifdef DEE 
    sum++;
#endif
#ifdef EEE 
    sum++;
#endif
    printf("The sum is %d\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: Would there be something similar for target_link_options under CMake < 3.6? I'm seeing it was introduced in 3.13.

Comment: Before `taget_link_options` people used `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks! Although I need to use /EHsc windows specific flag as a link flag, which target_link_libraries will error out on...

Comment: Try `set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} /EHsc")` but that's globally. For target specific, I would rather suggest updating cmake - it's still an active project with many bit changes. But really, `target_link_libraries( ... -EHsc)` should work, did you try it? (not `/` but `-`)

Comment: @KamilCuk I have another noob question you might be able to answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65777829/cmake-3-6-passing-multiple-flags-used-in-custom-command-with-dcmake-cxx-flag)